# Emulating Sequence with my own function

Tags: programming

I just considered if/how one could implement `Sequence` in Mathematica if it were not predefined. It turned out that the following simple definition has in all my tests exactly the right behaviour:

```
myseq /: f_[x___, myseq[y___], z___] := f[x, y, z]
```

Now my question: Does this already correctly reproduce the full behaviour of `Sequence`, or is there something `Sequence` does but `myseq` doesn't which I missed in my tests?

Here's what I tested:

```
foo[myseq[a, b]]
(*
==> foo[a, b]
*)
Hold[mysec[a,b]]
(*
==> Hold[a, b]
*)
HoldComplete[myseq[a,b]]
(*
HoldComplete[myseq[a, b]]
*)
Hold[f[myseq[a,b]]]
(*
==> Hold[f[myseq[a, b]]]
*)
f[myseq[myseq[a,b],c,d],e,myseq[f,g,myseq[]]]
(*
==> f[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
*)
```

Comment: One situation where `myseq` fails is for something like `{1, 2, 3} /. 2 -> myseq[a, b]`.

Comment: `t = {{a, b}, {c, d}, f}; myseq @@t` fails

Comment: @Heike That is because it doesn't support `SequenceHold` like `Sequnce` does.

Comment: @Szabolcs I just figured that out.

Comment: @belisarius `myseq[1,2]` does the same.  It may also be due to the lack of `SequenceHold` support.  EDIT: it's not.  Support can be added with `myseq /: f_[x___, myseq[y___], z___] /; 
  FreeQ[Attributes[f], SequenceHold] := f[x, y, z]`

Comment: Ah, so the answer to my question is "no". Looking at the attributes of `Rule` I notice an attribute with the suggestive name `SequenceHold`. Adding ` /; !MemberQ[Attributes[f], SequenceHold]` to the definition seems to fix this problem. Any others?

Comment: Is the code up to date?

Comment: @belisarius: In which way does `t = {...}; myseq @@t` fail? I get the same result as with `Sequence`, except that of course I have a `myseq` instead of `Sequence` in the output. Is that what you considered "failing"?

Comment: @Rojo: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you've started suggesting changes to fix things in comments

Comment: @celtschk `myseq[1, 2]` gives me an error about `If` being called with 6 arguments, possibly during the formatting step (`ToBoxes`)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ah, I didn't get those errors because I directly typed into the kernel. Now trying the notebook interface I also get those errors. The `SequenceHold` test doesn't fix it either.

Comment: @Rojo: I didn't edit my post after initial submission, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @celtschk I always bump into the problem of needing to `Trace` or `Block` the evaluation that happens during formatting, not evaluating the input expression.  I always wanted to ask a question on this but I thought the answers wouldn't bring anything new ... maybe it's time to ask that question soon: in this case `ToBoxes` can't emulate the formatting step completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, my two cents. The answer seems to be - you can't. There are 3 "magic" symbols which are wired into the core evaluator much deeper than the rest: `Evaluate`, `Unevaluated`, and `Sequence`. You can't fully emulate any of those without essentially writing your own version of Mathematica evaluator on top of the built-in one.

For the record, I first read about it in the book of David Wagner, "Power programming with Mathematica - the Kernel", p.207. Which means - if this is correct, I take the credit, but if it is wrong, he is the one to blame :). But, seriously, there was nothing in my experience to contradict this. You may emulate *some* aspects of `Sequence`, but I would be very surprised if you could make a complete emulation (without writing your own evaluator on top of the system one).

Let me also add that, while it is hidden, you *do* use `Sequence` in your approach, since the `y___` pattern is internally destructured as `Sequence`.  Check this out:

```
ClearAll[myseq];
myseq /: f_[x___, myseq[y___], z___] := f[x, Head[Unevaluated[y]], z]
```

and now

```
f[1, myseq[], 5]
```

> ```
> f[1, Sequence, 5]
> ```

Comment: Leonid, I hate to disappoint but I think you're getting a false result in your test.  I don't think `___` or `##` are implemented using `Sequence` though they are of course analogous.  In my opinion you cannot "catch" the `y` on the RHS in some intermediate form using `Unevaluated`.  You are instead seeing this:  `Head@Unevaluated[1, 2, 3]` yields `Sequence`; it is an effect of `Unevaluated`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd have to sit down and experiment a bit to find *where* exactly, but I've seen `__` and`##` transform into `Sequence` before.  I think they do make use of `Sequence` at some point during their evaluation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, you may be right, but I feel that `Unevaluated` should have nothing to do with that, it has a different purpose. OTOH, it is very natural that `__` and `##` use `Sequence` internally, since it is the same mechanism behind al of them. Perhaps, a better statement would be that all sequences are using the same underlying mechanism. I also second Szabolcs, I seem to remember cases where `Sequence` was appearing in the evaluation of `__` and `##` - related code. Will also try to find those cases.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, check this out: `HoldComplete[1, 2, ff[3, 4, 5], 6, 7] /. ff[y__] :> y`.

Comment: I almost second @Mr.Wizard except for the part where `Unevaluated` has a role (which I just don't have any hunch at all). I don't think Leonid's example proves that in his solution there's an internal use of `Sequence`. I imagine that when the replacer builds the expression :>rhs, if it a sequence, it has no other choice than to wrapping it in Sequence before putting it wherever it should be put. But that doesn't apply to his proposed solution, it's not a `f[sth___]:=sth` definition but something like `ff[2, 3] /. ff[x___] :> HoldComplete[x]`which seems to avoid `Sequence`

Comment: Perhaps there's another internal sequence-like thing used that evaluates to Sequence in the end, but flattens itself out even in HoldComplete. No idea, but I think we are all guessing big about internals that probably won't ever be relevant :P

Comment: @Rojo sorry, have you seen my last comment? If so, please tell me, how else than the way I did can you explain the result of this: `HoldComplete[1, 2, ff[3, 4, 5], 6, 7] /. ff[y__] :> y`. By your (or Mr.Wizard's) logic, we should get here `HoldComplete[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, while we get `HoldComplete[1,2,Sequence[3,4,5],6,7]`. I'd rather think that his examples reveal some inconsistency in the pattern-matching / destructuring, than the other way around.

Comment: What would you have `Head@Unevaluated[1,2]` return, or `y[x__] := x; y[2, 3]` or `{1, 2} /. {l__} :> l`? Sequence is the standard way in MMA to represent sequences of arguments, and I see no other reasonable alternative. However, where there are alternatives such as in `{1, 2} /. {l__} :> HoldComplete[l]`, `l__` is shown to represent the "real" sequence and not a `_Sequence` expression

Comment: @Rojo Ok, you may or may not be right. Pattern-matcher is sufficently separated from evaluation process so that this could be true, but also sufficiently integrated into it that it could be not. This is really a question of how deep the pattern-matcher is integrated with the evaluator, in this particular respect.

Comment: I agree 100% now. Answering your previous comment, I think of replace and family as something that works in 3 steps: match, build, replace. In the first 2, there are clearly deep internal things going on since `__` matches "real" sequences. Same for the building. But the expression built has to be a MMA expression.

Answer (score 5):

I think an issue that you will never be able to completely solve is one of priorities. `Sequence` is flattened before upvalues. So, for starters

```
ClearAll[f];
f /: g[f, _] := 9
```

So

```
g[f, myseq[2, 3]]
```

> 9

but

```
g[f, Sequence[2, 3]]
```

> g[f, 2, 3]

Comment: +1. This is just one manifestation of what I meant by saying that `Sequence` is deeply wired in the evaluation procedure.

Answer (score 2):

There are functions related to `Sequence`: `BlankSequence`, `BlankNullSequence` and `SlotSequence`.  These can be used to perform operations similar to `Sequence` but they are not identical.

As pointed out in the comments `Sequence` obeys the attribute `SequenceHold`:

```
SetAttributes[test, SequenceHold]

test[ Sequence[1, 2, 3] ]
```

> ```
> test[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
> ```

The others do not:

```
{1, 2, 3} /. _[x__] :> test[x]

test[##] &[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> test[1, 2, 3]
>
> test[1, 2, 3]
> ```

In fact these operations succeed even if `test` has `HoldAllComplete`.

You could emulate this behavior at least in part by modifying your definition to check for `SequenceHold`:

```
myseq /: f_[x___, myseq[y___], z___] /; 
  FreeQ[Attributes @ Unevaluated @ f, SequenceHold] := f[x, y, z]
```

Unlike the functions above `Unevaluated` uses `Sequence`:

```
test[1, Evaluate@Unevaluated[5, 6], 3]
```

> ```
> test[1, Sequence[5, 6], 3]
> ```