# Splicing a list of arguments into a function with Sequence

Tags: syntax, faq

Not sure if this has been asked, but I have a fairly simple operation that I don't know the syntax for. Say I have an array with some values, and a function f that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. The following:

```
array = {e,f};
f[a, b, c, d, array];
```

...is functionally equivalent to:

```
f[a, b, c, d, {e, f}];
```

OK, will Sequence help? Nope, this does the same thing:

```
f[a, b, c, d, Sequence@array];
```

Essentially, I want to include e and f into the list of arguments, i.e. I want to know the syntax for telling Mathematica I want it to evaluate this:

```
f[a, b, c, d, e, f];
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What about renaming the question to something like "Splicing a list of arguments into a function with Sequence" or similar?

Comment: Sure, sounds better to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Splice` came with V 12.1:

```
array = {e, f};

foo[a, b, c, d, Splice[array, foo]]
```

foo[a, b, c, d, e, f]

If we `Splice` a list of elements inside an expression with a `Head` other than `List` we must pass this `Head` (foo) as 2nd argument.

Compare to

```
List[a, b, c, d, Splice[array]]
```

{a, b, c, d, e, f}

Comment: The second argument functionality was like introduced in v13.1. I use v12.2.0 and it doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 29):

`Sequence` means more or less "no head". What you want to do is to *remove* the head `List` from an inner list. Or, put in another way, you want to replace this head with "no head". The operation that changes one head to another is `Apply`. Therefore, what you really want is

```
f[a, b, c, d, Sequence @@ array]
```

where `@@` stands for `Apply`.

Comment: Half of my Mathematica questions are answered by adding one more @ symbol... :)

Comment: @Guillochon Thanks for the accept, although you could have given it some more time - perhaps someone would come up with a better answer.

Comment: In this case, the answer was so simple that I didn't think anyone could do better. That being said, perhaps something should be added to the Etiquette section of the FAQ to indicate that one should wait some amount of time before accepting?

Comment: @Guillochon This may be a good idea.

Comment: +1 Great explanation. The first sentence should be in the documentation :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks :-). I came up with this when writing a book, so just borrowed from there.

Comment: Incidently, the answer also solved my problem, i.e. appending a given argument to a given function with other given arguments, like input G(a,b), output G(a,b,c). f[z_, y_] := G @@ Join[List @@ z, {y}] (Which can be done more elegantly, I guess, but it works.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann You could just do `Append[Unevaluated[G[a, b]], c]`, given that both input and output for your case have the same head.

Comment: I realized that actually I need a bit more: Lists with arbitrary occurences of G like {u*G[a,b],v*G[c,d]} shall be replaced by {u*G[a,b,e],v*G[c,d,e]}. The list part a /@ should do, but how to fish out the G?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann You might be better off creating a separate question with exact requirements you have.

Comment: Wanted to try it myself first :-) Here is my hack: Convert to string, replace ] by ,e] , revert to expression, done. :-) (Of course this only works since my requirements are weak - ] doesn't occur elsewhere.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I would avoid converting to strings and back, like a plague. You never know when this will bite you. There certainly are much better options available.

Answer (score 12):

You can certainly bypass the use of `Sequence[]` (though it is certainly a neat thing):

```
f[a, b, c, d, ##] & @@ array
   f[a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Comment: +1. The extent to which this can be called "bypassing" depends on whether or not `SlotSequence` (`##`) uses `Sequence` internally. One thing I am certain about is that both use the same underlying mechanism. In particular, `Sequence @@ array` can be also written as `##& @@ array` (a form beloved by @Mr.Wizard). The discussion in comments below my answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/emulating-sequence-with-my-own-function) seems relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, neither of the existing answers will work as written when working with held expressions.  That case is addressed in:

- [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121)

The most concise solution I know is what I have come to call the "injector pattern" in reference to that Q&A, for lack of another term.

Let's say our function is `foo` and we want to insert arguments from `seq`.

```
SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll];

seq = Hold[1/0, 8/4];

seq /. _[x__] :> foo[1, 2, x]
```

> ```
> foo[1, 2, 1/0, 8/4]
> ```

Compare this to the result of the other two methods shown:

```
foo[1, 2, Sequence @@ seq]
```

> ```
> foo[1, 2, Sequence @@ seq]
> ```

```
foo[1, 2, ##] & @@ seq
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>
> ```
> foo[1, 2, ComplexInfinity, 2]
> ```

The [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) method can be adapted by giving the anonymous function a HoldAll attribute but this requires the use of an undocumented form:

```
Function[, foo[1, 2, ##], HoldAll] @@ seq
```

> ```
> foo[1, 2, 1/0, 8/4]
> ```

Reference:

- [Pure function with attributes of arbitrary number of arguments: Is it possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121)

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
Sequence @@@ g[a, b, c, d, array]
## & @@@ g[a, b, c, d, array]
FlattenAt[g[a, b, c, d, array], -1]
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e, f]

Comment: The first two are hardly general as other elements (a, b, c, d) cannot be assumed to be atomic.  The last one is interesting but I think it better applies to a [slightly different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50381/121).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to delete the Head with
[`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html)

```
array = {e, f};

foo[a, b, c, d, Delete[array,0]]

(* foo[a,b,c,d,e,f] *)

Delete[{-1,0}]@foo[a, b, c, d,array]

(* foo[a,b,c,d,e,f] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `Replace` for the particular position the array has in your example:

```
array = {e, f};
Replace[#, x_ :> Sequence @@ x, {1 - Depth[#]}] &@g[a, b, c, d, e, h, array];

(*g[a, b, c, d, e, h, e, f]*)
```

Or using `ReplacePart`, `Position` and `Extract` for any positions of the arrays:

```
s = ReplacePart[#, Thread[Position[#, x_List] -> 
    Function[x, Sequence @@ x[[1]]]@
    Extract[#, Position[#, x_List]]]] &;

s@g[a, b, c, d, array, m, h, array]

(*g[a, b, c, d, e, f, m, h, e, f]*)
```