# Composition with Apply

Tags: functional-style

`Composition` is sometimes useful for clarity of a code. For the same purpose I try to `Apply(@@)` functions as often as it is possible.

**My question is how to combine** `Composition` with `Apply`, or, to be more precise, is there any simpler way than one I'm going to show (there is no `Composition` :)):

```
Fold[#2@@#1&, arg, {f1, f2,...}]
```

alternatively:

```
Fold[Apply[#2,#1]&, arg, {f1, f2,...}]
```

So for **example**:

```
Fold[#2 @@ #1 &, {1, 2}, {{##} &, {#2, #1} &, {#1, 0, #2} &}]
```

> ```
> {2, 0, 1}
> ```

Comment: Not as compact as your version using `Fold[]`, so I'm not posting this as an answer: `(Composition @@ Function[f, Apply[f, #] &] /@ {{#1, 0, #2} &, {#2, #1} &, {##1} &})[{1, 2}]`.

Comment: @0x4A4D I think the following would be useful functionality: `Composition[f1,f2..., Method->k][__]` where `k` can be `Apply, Map, MapIndexed` etc.

Comment: It is hardly simpler, but you can use something like `Composition[Apply @@ # &, Reverse, List]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there can be something syntactically simpler than `Fold[#2@@#1, ...`, but if you often find yourself doing something more complicated with the `Head`s of expressions (in this case, replacing them), you might want to look at [`Operate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Operate.html), which hasn't showed up much on this site.

You can adapt it to your specific example with `Fold` as follows:

```
Fold[Function[{arg, f}, Operate[f &, arg]], {1, 2}, {{##} &, {#2, #1} &, {#1, 0, #2} &}]
(* {2, 0, 1} *)
```

What we're doing here is to "operate" on the head of the input expression by discarding it and replacing it with the next element fed to `Fold`. (Note the use of nested pure functions.)

Comment: this is educational, thanks.

Comment: I don't think there can be something syntactically simpler than Fold[#2@@#1, ..., :)) +1

Comment: hmm, a bit of the core language (i.e. v1, core!) I've never seen. Weird. +1