# Unwrapping a list when invoking a function

Tags: function-construction, core-language

The minimal working example of my problem is as follows:

```
l = {1, 2, 3, 4}
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] = a + b + c + d
```

Now, I'd like to evaluate

```
f[l[[1]],l[[2]],l[[3]],l[[4]]]
```

, but with a syntax like `f[Unwrap[l]]`.

I don't have access to the code of 'f', and I can't simply change the way it is defined to accept a list

Basically, I am missing the functionality present in Python with the *,

```
l=[0,1,2,3]
def f(a,b,c,d):
    return a+b+c+d
print f(*l)
```

Comment: `list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] = a + b + c + d;
f[Sequence @@ list]` ?

Comment: f@@l does the trick ;) (python pah!)

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/splicing-a-list-of-arguments-into-a-function-with-sequence/) question.

Comment: Sorry, this had already been asked.

Comment: @rm-fr If this link should be considered canonical Q&A maybe You will put there `Operate` based answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this that are mostly equivalent.  First,

```
f[ Sequence @@ l ]
(* 10 *)
```

But, the use of `Sequence` is to many characters, in my opinion, and there is a better way. Essentially, the notation `@@` is shorthand for the function `Apply` which replaces the `Head` of an expression with another head. In the prior case, `Sequence` replaced the head `List` which was then passed into `f`. But, this can be used directly,

```
f @@ l
(* 10 *)
```

which replaces the head `List` with `f`.

Answer (score 1):

and the third one ([thanks to rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27309/5478))

```
l = {a, b, c, s};
Operate[f &, l]
```

> ```
> f[a, b, c, s]
> ```

but in such simple case f@@l is what I use.