# Is there a function in Mathematica which removes brackets wrapping an expression?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Is there a function in *Mathematica* which removes brackets from an expression?

```
RemoveBrackets[ {3} ]
```

> 3

*Note: inspired by @garej's answer to this question* :[Brackets around each item in matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105864/36681)

- further edits/comments/answers welcome

Comment: related: [21174](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21174/5478)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is closely related to:

- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)
- [How to completely delete the head of a function expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50381/121)

If you wish to strip the brackets from a single expression in a nontrivial case please consider [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) as described in my answer to the second referenced question above.

- Unlike using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (e.g. `# & @@ {1}` or `Sequence @@ {1}`) it does not first replace `List` with something else which means it behaves better inside held expressions.
- Unlike `Part`, `First`, etc. it works equally well with multiple arguments, allowing us to strip the `{}` from e.g. `HoldComplete[{1, 2, 3}]` using `// Delete[{1, 0}]`.

If you wish to strip brackets throughout an expression you can use the methods from the first linked question, being mindful of the tradeoff between brevity and efficiency.

```
expr = {{0, {{1, 2}}, {3}}, {4}};

expr //. {x_} :> x
```

> ```
> {{0, {1, 2}, 3}, 4}
> ```

```
Replace[expr, {x_} :> x, {0, -2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, {1, 2}, 3}, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I learned from @Kuba:

```
First[{3}]
```

> 3

```
#& @@{3}
```

> 3

these do this task  even more generally than I imagined.

given any Atomic expressions wrapped with any function  >> the FullForm of almost everthing in Mathematica

*ArbitraryHead[expr1, expr2 ]*

```
First[ArbitraryHead[expr1, expr2]]
```

> expr1

```
#&@@ArbitraryHead[expr1,expr2]
```

> expr1

---

---

here are specific examples:

---

```
First[(1/a^2)]
```

> a

why?:

```
 (1/a^2)//FullForm
```

> Power[a, -2]

---

```
First[List[3]]
```

> 3

P.S. I feel this community is building a tall cathedral of knowledge. I'm doing my little bit of brickwork.

---

---

```
{3}[[1]]
```

> 3

---

```
##& @@{3}
```

> 3

---

```
Seqence[{3}]
```

> Sequence[3]

Comment: Don't forget `Part` and `Sequence`.

Comment: I agree, I've always been partial to using `a[[1]]` instead of `First[a]`

Comment: `Seqence[{3}]` evaluates to `Seqence[{3}]` -- did you forget something?

Comment: FYI: [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) is a defined function with a specific purpose, and best not used as an arbitrary inert head in an example.