# Do with variables from a table

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I want to perform a `Do` command with `n` variables, where `n` is set elsewhere in my code. How do I do that?

For example, suppose `s={0,1}` and `n=2`, then I want a code that runs

```
Do[Print[{var1,var2}],{var1,s},{var2,s}]
```

and when I set `n=3`, then I want a code that runs

```
Do[Print[{var1,var2,var3}],{var1,s},{var2,s},{var3,s}].
```

(`Print` is used just as a simple example here.) I have tried

```
Do[Print[ToExpression[Table["i"<>ToString[i],{i, n}]]],ToExpression[Table["{i"<>ToString[i]<>",s}",{i, 1, n}]]]
```

but Mathematica complains due to the result of the second `ToExpression` containing extra pair of curly brackets (`Table` produces a list). I tried removing these brackets with `Row` (as suggested https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1219718) or `Delete` (as suggested here [Is there a function in Mathematica which removes brackets wrapping an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106052/is-there-a-function-in-mathematica-which-removes-brackets-wrapping-an-expression)), but could not get code to work due to my limited knowledge of Mathematica.

I know I can do `Tuples` but that produces a large output when `s` is large (i.e., requires a lot of memory).

I will appreciate any comments.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve in the end? Here's an easy way to compute an arbitrary dimensional array where the elements are the sums of indices. `Array[Total[{##}] &, {3, 4, 2}]` Notice that it generalizes to $n$ dimensions without problem. Can you explain your use case in enough detail that it becomes apparent why such a solution would not be possible for you?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Apologies for the missing context. I am trying to generate all `n` dimensional vectors such that a) all elements are drawn from `s`, b) the elements sum to 1 and c) the elements are increasing. One way to do this is to generate all `n` tuples from `s` and then test each tuple for a)-c). However, this generates all tuples at ones and requires a lot of memory when `s` is large.

Comment: Since the elements must be increasing, I would use `Subsets`, not `Tuples`. This will improve performance significantly because you just got rid of a lot of permutations. If there are still too many subsets, you can use `Subsets`'s 3rd argument to only generate the `n`th one, thus being able to iterate through them without generating all of them first.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you. Let me confirm that using `Subsets` works as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop over what would be the result of `Tuples[s, {n}]` without generating all tuples at once, then you need to recall that tuple generation is isomorphic to generating $n$-digit base-$b$ numbers, where `b == Length[s]`:

```
n = 3; s = {0, 1};
b = Length[s];
Do[Print[s[[IntegerDigits[k, b, n] + 1]]], {k, 0, b^n - 1}]
```

Otherwise, there is the option of programatically generating the iterators:

```
Do[Print[Array[K, n]], ##] & @@ ({#, s} & /@ Array[K, n])
```

Here, I use `K[n]` as the loop variable for each level.

Comment: There are 3 suggested ways to do what I originally asked: `Subsets`, $n$-digit base-$b$ and `Array`. All three work as intended. The $n$-digit base-$b$ seems to be the fastest.