# How to completely delete the head of a function expression

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, core-language

Is there any way to completely remove the head of an expression function?

For example, how would I remove the head `Cos` from `Cos[a]` to give only `a` as an output.

Comment: `First@Cos[a]`?

Comment: Note that all expressions have heads and bodies. These two are not separable. For example, `a` has head `Symbol`. All you can do is to replace a head with something else or extract parts of an expression.

Comment: @Oleksandr I agree and would think that the closest thing to a headless expression is one with `Sequence` as head.

Comment: @acl `Identity`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I was thinking about things like `Sequence @@@ List[List[a, b], List[a, c]]`. But you're right, for examples like in your answer `Identity` does the job.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can actually [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Delete.html) the head of the expression, which is part `0`:

```
Delete[#, 0] & /@ {Cos[a], Sin[b], Tan[c]}
```

> ```
> {a, b, c}
> ```

With version 10 [operator forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121):

```
Delete[0] /@ {Cos[a], Sin[b], Tan[c]}
```

> ```
> {a, b, c}
> ```

One case of interest may be held expressions.  If our expression is:

```
expr = HoldComplete[2 + 2];
```

And the head we wish to remove is `Plus`, we *cannot* use these:

```
Identity @@@ expr
Sequence @@@ expr
expr /. Plus -> Identity
expr /. Plus -> Sequence
Replace[expr, _[x__] :> x, 1]
```

All produce e.g.:

```
HoldComplete[Identity[2, 2]]  (* or Sequence *)
```

We *can* use `Delete` or [`FlattenAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FlattenAt.html):

```
Delete[expr, {1, 0}]
FlattenAt[expr, 1]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[2, 2]
> HoldComplete[2, 2]
> ```

You could also use a pattern that includes the surrounding expression on the right-hand-side, as demonstrated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121), e.g.:

```
expr /. h_[_[x__]] :> h[x]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[2, 2]
> ```

---

#### Notes

As the documentation for `Delete` reads:

> Deleting the head of a whole expression makes the head be Sequence.

```
Delete[Cos[a], 0]
```

> ```
> Sequence[a]
> ```

Since this resolves to `a` in normal evaluation this should usually not be an issue.

Comment: +1, I like my held expressions. About "when there is no surrounding expression", I like this remark. To see that this is really the behaviour of `Delete`, rather than some post-processing of the kernel, you can evaluate: `SetAttributes[seqHHA, {SequenceHold, HoldAll}]; seqHHA@Evaluate@Delete[Cos[a], 0]`. So I disagree with your latest edit. The "a whole expression" here is the entire first argument of `Delete`, rather than any "subexpression" of the expression in the first argument.

Comment: @Jacob I'm not sure what your example is intended to illustrate, and I don't know why you disagree with what I said.  In your case you `Evaluate` `Delete[Cos[a], 0]` before `seqHHA` sees it, so there is effectively no surrounding expression.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jacob I just saw the addendum to your comment above, and I think I understand now, as well as I suppose what the documentation is saying.  Nevertheless I don't think that (the documentation) is written very clearly.

Comment: I agree that the documentation is not very clear. But such a mistake (of being vague) is easily made I guess :). I'm glad we looked at this, the behaviour of `Delete` w.r.t. generating `Sequence` has puzzled me before.

Comment: @Jacob Would not your example be better written like this?: `Attributes[seqHHA] = {SequenceHold}; seqHHA[Delete[Cos[a], 0]]`

Comment: I agree that that is better. It seems I was too cautious or something :). I think the `HoldAll` is irrelevant, but caution may be good. For example, `Sequence[symb]` may not resolve to `symb` if `symb` is intended to be a head, in for example `Delete[{Sin},0][Pi]`. Also compare this with `ReleaseHold`, i.e. `ReleaseHold[Hold[Sin]][Pi]`.

Answer (score 10):

Does this come close?

```
Cos[a] /. Cos[a] -> a
```

Or

```
Cos[a] /. _[a] -> a
```

Or

```
First@Cos[a]
```

Or

```
list = {Sin@a, Cos@b};
First /@ list
```

> {a, b}

Comment: The second one is good because you can apply it to functions without  need to retype the functions in Replace all. thanks eldo.

Comment: @Algohi- see my update :)

Comment: Your second example doesn't remove the head, it just matches `_[a]` with literally `a` then always returns `a`. For example `Cos[b]` isn't matched. I guess you meant `/. _[a___] -> a`, so that eg `lekker[b, c] /. _[a___] -> a` works.

Comment: @acl - Thanks - Just inspected the 4 forms by applying `Head` and `FullForm` to them - everything seems to be right.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that your examples don't work, but that if the argument is not `a` then it does not get matched, because the `a` on the right hand side of `/.` is not a pattern. eg `Cos[b] /. _[a] -> a` evaluates to `Cos[b]`, ie, the `a` is matched literally. You probably meant `Cos[b] /. _[a_] -> a` or, more generally (allowing for multiple arguments) `Cos[b] /. _[a___] -> a`.

Comment: @acl - ah ! now I got your interesting point. one can even write `Cos[b] /. _@a___ -> a` :)

Answer (score 10):

You remove a head by replacing it with `Identity`

`Cos[a] /. Cos -> Identity`

For doing this over lots of expressions:

```
list = {ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], Cot[x], Cot[z], Cot[x], 
  ArcTan[z], ArcTanh[y], ArcTanh[x], Cot[y]};

list[[All, 0]] = Identity
```

or

```
Identity @@@ list
```

etc

Answer (score 9):

`Sequence` might be useful if your expressions come inside other expressions. For example:

```
num = 10;
lst = MapThread[
  #1@#2 &,
  {
   RandomChoice[{Cos, Sin, Exp, Tan, Cot, ArcTan, ArcTanh}, num],
   RandomChoice[{x, y, z}, num]
   }
  ]

(*

{ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], Cot[x], Cot[z], Cot[x], ArcTan[z], 
 ArcTanh[y], ArcTanh[x], Cot[y]}

*)
```

(this is just a long-winded way of producing a list), then

```
Sequence @@ # & /@ lst

(*
{x, x, x, x, z, x, z, y, x, y}
*)
```

Roughly, `Sequence` dissolves and its children get promoted whenever it appears as something other than the topmost head, eg `f[Sequence[g]]` evaluates to `f[g]`. Thus,

```
expr = f @@ lst
Sequence @@ # & /@ expr

(*

f[ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x], Cot[x], Cot[z], Cot[x], ArcTan[z], 
 ArcTanh[y], ArcTanh[x], Cot[y]]

f[x, x, x, x, z, x, z, y, x, y]

*)
```

Comment: `Sequence @@ # & /@ lst` can be written more compactly as  `Sequence @@@ lst`

Comment: Note that `Sequence` will not evaluate inside a head with `HoldAllComplete` or `SequenceHold` attributes.

Comment: @BobHanlon Good point, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem and did not find good answer here.
Then I found Mathematica function `Level` is very usefull for this:

```
f=Cos[a];
Level[f, 1]
```

> {a}

Second argument in level defines the depth of subexpressions to be extracted.

```
Level[Cos[a + b], 1]
```

gives you:

> {a + b}

Meanwhile `Level[cos[a + b], {-1}]` completely opens subexpressions:

> {a, b}

You strategy with more complex functions than just Cos[a] could be either to undestand and use proper levelspec parameter, or try to change it iteratively looking for your `Head` in the output list.

Comment: Actually, this replaced `Cos` by `List`.

Comment: [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html?q=Level) can have a third argument, that can be used to put the result in something else other than `List`. For example, `Level[Cos[a + b], {-1}, HoldComplete]` or `Level[Cos[a + b], {-1}, Sequence]`.

Comment: +1 as `Level` is very useful for getting a list of arguments. For example `Level[Plus[a,b,c],1]` which you can now `Map`, `Select` or something else without having the `Plus` remain as a head of the output.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use `DeleteCases` (which also works inside held expressions):

```
DeleteCases[{Sin[Cos[x]], Cos[x], Hold[2 + 2], HoldComplete[2*3]}, 
 Cos | Plus | Times, -1, Heads -> True]

(*{Sin[x], x, Hold[2, 2], HoldComplete[2, 3]}*)
```