# How can I change a list to a sequence without destroying nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I defined a function `f` like

```
f[x___, y_] := something;
```

and if `x`s and `y` are all number, when I use this function, I would input like this:

```
f[1, 5, 3, 6, 3]
```

For this, `x = Sequence[1, 5, 3, 6]` and `y = 3`.

Suppose that I have a list `l = {1, 5, 3, 6}`.
Then I might use `f` like

```
f[l /. List -> Sequence, 3]
```

using `ReplaceAll` to convert `List` to `Sequence`.

It is very good way to convert I think.

But, the problem is, when I want to input

```
f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]
```

which is given by `l = {1, {5, 3}, 6}`, if I use `/.`, `ReplaceAll`, `{5, 3}` is also converted into the sequence so the whole input becomes `f[1, 5, 3, 6, 3]`, not `f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]`.

I have searched several alternative functions like `Replace` which includes a `levelspec` option. But `Replace` can not convert `List`.

How can I convert without loss of inside lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
l = {1, {5, 3}, 6}
```

Then use:

```
f[Sequence @@ l, 3]
```

> `f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]`

Comment: Wow, what a wonderful solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Analysis. You're welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: @RunnyKine +1 Your short solution seems to be very stable

Comment: Thank you.  This is just the ticket when needing to convert from a list to function entries.

Answer (score 8):

`Sequence @@` is probably the "right" way to do this for normal functions, but you should know that you can also use [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) or [`BlankSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) in [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) or replacement respectively:

```
l = {1, {5, 3}, 6}

f[##, 3] & @@ l
```

> ```
> f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]
> ```

```
l /. _[x__] :> f[x, 3]
```

> ```
> f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]
> ```

These become important in the case where `f` holds its arguments:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]

f[Sequence @@ l, 3]
f[##, 3] & @@ l
l /. _[x__] :> f[x, 3]
```

> ```
> f[Sequence @@ l, 3]
>
> f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]
>
> f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]
> ```

Note that `Sequence @@ l` does not evaluate.

Further distinction is apparent between the second two methods when the input is to be held:

```
l = Hold[1 + 1, {5!, 3/0}, 6 - 1];
```

This causes evaluation because the `Function` was not also given the `HoldAll` attribute:

```
f[##, 3] & @@ l
```

> During evaluation of In[22]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>
> ```
> f[2, {120, ComplexInfinity}, 5, 3]
> ```

This does not:

```
l /. _[x__] :> f[x, 3]
```

> ```
> f[1 + 1, {5!, 3/0}, 6 - 1, 3]
> ```

Reference: [Injecting a sequence of expressions into a held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1929/121)

Comment: Thanks for adding other scenarios. +1

Answer (score 4):

If it is just a matter of replacing the first List, then this could work also:

```
l = {1, {5, 3}, 6};
f[Delete[l, 0], 3]

(*f[1, {5, 3}, 6, 3]*)
```

Comment: Nice to see that you [remember!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50401/121) +1 :-)

Comment: you always inspire me and your answer stick in my mind as far as I understand them :)

Comment: That makes me happy.  Thanks. :-)