# How to extract arguments of functions in an expression?

Tags: argument-patterns

How can I extract the argument of a function in an expression?

```
expr=b[c];
```

I need some f[expr] that will return c.

d[f[expr]]  ->  d[c]

Comment: On reflection I think that this question, if no additional detail is added, can be closed as a duplicate of [(50381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50381/121) since all methods below are given there and with greater detail.

Answer (score 6):

Using patterns for [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring):

```
expr = b[c];

f[_[x__]] := x

d[f[expr]]
```

> ```
> d[c]
> ```

Or more directly with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
d @@ expr
```

> ```
> d[c]
> ```

Both forms also works with multiple arguments:

```
 d[ f[ p[1, 2, 3] ] ]
```

> ```
> d[1, 2, 3]
> ```

```
d @@ p[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> d[1, 2, 3]
> ```

Also see:

- [How to completely delete the head of a function expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50381/121)

Answer (score 4):

Your example is a little unclear to me but if you're asking for a list of the arguments then

```
List @@ expr
```

does the job.  This is the short form of `Apply[List, expr]` it simply replaces the head of `expr`, in your example `b`, by `List`.

Comment: This is far more elegant and idiomatic than any solution I've seen on this site +1.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does this:

```
f[e_] := e[[1]]
```

This works because all expressions have the same internal form, `head[arg1, ..., argn]` and `e[[1]]` really just accesses the first argument, `arg1`, without caring for the head.. Since `{a, b, c}` is just syntactic sugar for `List[a, b, c]`, also `{a,b,c}[[1]]` returns `a`.