# I'm not able to delete -> in {{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}}

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, rule

Here is what I have done.

Input

```
DeleteCases[{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}}, Rule, {2}]
```

Output

```
{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}}
```

Why is it not `{{x, a}, {x, b}, {{x, c}, {x, d}}}`?

Comment: `{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}} /. (x_ -> a_) :> {x, a} /. {{a__}} :> {a}` also works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) does not by default operate on heads.  You can set the [`Heads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) option to `True` to change that.

```
DeleteCases[{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}}, Rule, {3}, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {{x, a}, {x, b}, {x, c, x, d}}
> ```

Note that the last term has become `{x, c, x, d}` which is not quite what you expected, but it is logically consistent if we expect `{x -> a}` to become `{x, a}`.

A simpler path to the same output in this case is:

```
{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}} /. Rule -> Sequence
```

> ```
> {{x, a}, {x, b}, {x, c, x, d}}
> ```

Your expected output can be had from:

```
{{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}} /. Rule -> List /. {x_List} :> x
```

> ```
> {{x, a}, {x, b}, {{x, c}, {x, d}}}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [How to completely delete the head of a function expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50381/121)

Comment: Is it possible to use `Apply` to 2nd levelspec?

Comment: @kile Yes!  You could write `Apply[Sequence, {{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}}, {2}]`  But understand that `Sequence` must evaluate, so this is not directly deleting the head.  See the "Recommended reading" link for details.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing heads is generically supported by [`Apply (@@ / @@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html). So a functional way may look like this:

```
rules = {{x -> a}, {x -> b}, {x -> c, x -> d}};
If[Length[#] == 1, Flatten[#], Identity[#]] & /@ Apply[List, rules, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{x, a}, {x, b}, {{x, c}, {x, d}}}
> ```

Or

```
If[Length[#] == 1, Sequence @@@ #, List @@@ #] & /@ rules
```

returns the same result.