# Extracting argument of a specific functions in a large expression

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, core-language

I have a large expression, for example

```
Cos[x]Sin[y]Sqrt[1+z]/(1+x^2)-1/(1+y)
```

I wish to extract the argument inside `Sqrt` function, namely `1+z`. I thought of using `/.Sqrt[x_]->(h=x)`, but executing

```
Cos[x]Sin[y]Sqrt[1+z]/(1+x^2)-1/(1+y)/.Sqrt[x_]->(h=x);h
```

returns `x` but not `1+z`, why? Is there a way to achieve my goal?

In my expressions, there will only be one `Sqrt`, but many other different heads as well. There is a [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50381) question, but it is only applicable to very simple expression like `Sqrt[1+z]`.

Comment: You did not get what you expected because you used [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)(`->`) rather than [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)(`:>`)

Comment: @BobHanlon  I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Cos[x] Sin[y] Sqrt[1 + z]/(1 + x^2) - 1/(1 + y) Sqrt[1 - z];

Cases[expr, Sqrt[t_] :> t, Infinity]

(* {1 - z, 1 + z} *)
```

To ensure that all of the terms are real

```
And @@ Thread[% >= 0] // Simplify

(* -1 <= z <= 1 *)
```

Or more directly,

```
And @@ Cases[expr, Sqrt[t_] :> (t >= 0), Infinity] // Simplify

(* -1 <= z <= 1 *)
```

Better yet,

```
FunctionDomain[expr, z]

(* -1 <= z <= 1 *)
```