# How to set up Switch with variable number of conditionals?

Tags: programming, conditional

I would like to use a Switch command with IntegerPartitions[n] of terms with n ranging from 3 to 12 and n chosen at run time.  I have:

```
monodromyTypes = IntegerPartitions[n];
switchCodes = Flatten[Table[{monodromyTypes[], i}, {i, 1,Length[monodromyTypes]}], 1];
```

Then:

```
switchCodes={{4}, 1, {3, 1}, 2, {2, 2}, 3, {2, 1, 1}, 4, {1, 1, 1, 1}, 5}
```

and I would like now to use switchCodes in a Switch statement like:

```
Switch[monodromy,{4}, 1, {3, 1}, 2, {2, 2}, 3, {2, 1, 1}, 4, {1, 1, 1, 1}, 5]
```

However I can't simply code Switch[monodromy,switchCodes].  I suspect I need to use Sequence but do not know how and was wondering if someone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Like `Switch[monodromy, ##] & @@ switchCodes`, then?

Comment: The reason that you had difficulty using `Sequence` is that `Switch` has the attribute `HoldRest`. Consequently, you would need to use `Evaluate` to override the `HoldRest`, i.e., `Switch[monodromy, Evaluate[Sequence @@ switchCodes]]`. Also, in your initial definition of `switchCodes`, I believe that `monodromyTypes[]` should read `monodromyTypes[[i]]`

Comment: I think this should be marked as a duplicate of [(19277)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19277/121), but that Q&A should also be extended to expressly address held arguments even though user5844's answer implicitly solves that.