# Using Apply or unpacking lists for only some arguments of a function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Say I have a function `f` of three parameters and a list `l = {b,c}`. I want to pass the first parameter to `f` manually, and use `l` for the other two. I can use `Apply` like this:

```
f[a, #1, #2]& @@ l
```

Is there a shorter expression, similar to how in Python I would just do `f(a, *l)`? Ideally I wouldn't have to specify the number of parameters (for convenience, mostly).

Of course the version with `Apply` works - I'm just interested to see if there's a neater version. The equivalent Python has the advantage that `l` appears inside the function where it should be, making it easier to read.

Comment: `f[a, Sequence @@ l]` is what you are probably after.

Comment: @Leonid it sure does, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: There is one caveat however, which is not discussed in the linked question. If your function `f` happens to have `Hold` attributes (in your case, `HoldRest` or `HoldAll`), then in general `f[a, #1, #2]& @@ l` and `f[a, Sequence @@ l]` are not equivalent, and in some cases you will find the former working while the latter not. For example, `ClearAll[f]; SetAttributes[f, HoldRest]; f[x_, rest___Integer] := Plus[x, rest]`. This will work fine when user as e.g. `f[1, #1, #2]& @@ {2, 3}`, but it will not evaluate when used as `f[1, Sequence @@ {2, 3}]`.

Answer (score 1):

*Conversion of @Leonid Shifrin's comments into a community wiki answer:*

**Leonid Shifrin:**

`f[a, Sequence @@ l]` is what you are probably after.

Does this answer your question? [Splicing a list of arguments into a function with Sequence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/splicing-a-list-of-arguments-into-a-function-with-sequence)

There is one caveat however, which is not discussed in the linked question. If your function `f` happens to have `Hold` attributes (in your case, `HoldRest` or `HoldAll`), then in general `f[a, #1, #2]& @@ l` and `f[a, Sequence @@ l]` are not equivalent, and in some cases you will find the former working while the latter not. For example, `ClearAll[f]; SetAttributes[f, HoldRest]; f[x_, rest___Integer] := Plus[x, rest]`. This will work fine when used as e.g. `f[1, #1, #2]& @@ {2, 3}`, but it will not evaluate when used as `f[1, Sequence @@ {2, 3}]`.